# Nightwatch using same element selector for each call

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

Is there a way to avoid using element's selector twice or more when executing several actions on the same element?

E.g.
('Some test', function (browser) {
browser
.waitForElementVisible('selector', 10000)
.click('THE SAME selector')
}),

Can't it be arranged just like in Cypress?

```
Cy
  .get('element')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()    - like 3 actions with only one mentioning of the element's selector
```

Or to save the element as a variable and use it then?

I have searched throughout the Internet but haven't found any proper topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that you would do this is to move the locator into a [page object](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/using-page-objects/getting-started.html) or into a variable as described in the [API Docs](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/click.html#apimethod-container)

The reason why NightwatchJS doesn't follow the Cypress pattern is that we allow chaining of all commands. This means that you can create more complex tests.

```
const githubButton = 'a[aria-label="Nightwatch on Github"]';

  before(browser => browser.navigateTo('https://nightwatchjs.org/'));

  after(browser => browser.end());

  it('click element', function (browser) {
    browser
      .click(githubButton)
  });
```

A click can only happen if it is visible in Nightwatch so you don't need to add an assert for it before clicking